# Programmatically run Microsft Store and sign in to Microsoft account

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

My program receives data from a Microsoft account from a remote server (login / password), now I need to start Microsoft Store on the user's computer, log out of the current Microsoft account, and log in with a new account. Hint at least in which direction to look, Windows API or other options?
Preferably in Delphi, but examples in other languages will work.

P.S.In the screenshot, I marked which window I need to launch and which account to change.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw9at.jpg)

Comment: It seems pretty unlikely there would be a supported way of doing this.

Comment: I know at least two programs that do exactly this, but I don’t understand how this is implemented. I have no source code.

Comment: The [supported URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app) for the Microsoft Store application do not expose any account-related operations.

Comment: Are you connecting to the user's computer remotely? If yes, do you use third-party app or winapi? Such as WMI.